# Infinite Amount of Command Line Arguments in Python

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to create a simple calculator where it accepts arguments at the command line. For example at the command line:

```
Calculator.py 1 2 44 6 -add
```

will give me the sum of the numbers. However, how can the user input infinite amount of arguments. I know you have to use *args or something of the like in functions and i just wanted to know how to incorporate that in the command line using argparse.

Comment: Can you paste the code in calculator . py?

Comment: what tells you that the number of args is limited? whatever arguments are passed are just stored in sys.argv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
               help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
               const=sum, default=max,
               help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.accumulate(args.integers)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: vik, thank you.  I'm still figuring out the formatting on this.

Comment: This is lifted straight from the documentation. Sources please! (Unless it's the other way around...)

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to, command line arguments are stored in [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) which will give you a list of the command line arguments. You just need to sum over them.

```
from sys import argv

print sum(map(int, argv[1:]))  # We take a slice from 1: because the 0th argument is the script name.
```

And just do

```
python testScript.py 1 2 3
6
```

**P.S** - Command line arguments are stored as strings, so you need to `map` them to integers to sum over them.

`*args` is used when you need to pass unknown number of values to a function. Consider the following -

```
>>> def testFunc(*args):
        return sum(args)

>>> testFunc(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
21
```

Comment: Isn't this ignoring the -add flag?

Comment: You could get the -add flag by slicing argv[1:-1] and then handling argv[-1] separately?

Comment: If the OP knows that the last element is going to be a function for calculation, he can just slice it accordingly and test for the function. I added the part about unknown arguments to functions.

Comment: You can use `-add` too, just slice the list from `[1:-1]` and set up a dictionary containing flags to functions mapping. Then, just pass `argv[1:-1]` to the function as a list and print out the sum using `sum(map(int, passedArg))`.

Comment: -xxx usually implies the parameter can occur anywhere on the line.  (OK, I'm kind of being a turd here.....)  Maybe grab it and repack the list of args?

Comment: You can iterate through the list in that case, finding any function that is a key in your dictionary mapping, remove it from the list and pass the remaining slice to the appropriate function.

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse

def operate_numbers(numbers, operation):
    return operation(*numbers)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Simple calculator script")
    parser.add_argument('numbers', type=int, nargs='+', help='Numbers to operate on')
    parser.add_argument('-operation', choices=['add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide'], required=True, help='Operation to perform')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    operations = {
        'add': sum,
        'subtract': lambda x: x[0] - sum(x[1:]),
        'multiply': lambda x: eval('*'.join(map(str, x))),
        'divide': lambda x: eval('/'.join(map(str, x)))
    }

    result = operate_numbers(args.numbers, operations[args.operation])
    print("Result:", result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers aren't particularly helpful to the community, would you mind editing your answer to add a description of what your snippet does?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).